# Image not showing above list Ionic

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I am trying to put a full width image with certain height at the top of the ionic page (under the nav, before the list).  The image does work as I put it in the list, it's just not showing at the top.  Any ideas?

```
<ion-view view-title="{{pageTitle}}">
  <ion-content>
    <img ng-src="{{post.acf.top_image_full_list}}">
  <ion-list>
      <div class="list">
        <a ng-repeat="post in posts"
           href="#/tab/watch/{{current_category_id}}/{{post.id}}"
           class="item item-thumbnail-left">

            <img ng-src="{{post.acf.top_single_msg}}">
            <div class="postcat">
            <span style="font-size: 17px;">{{post.title.rendered}}</span>
            <p>{{post.date | date}}</p></div>
        </a>
      </div>
    </ion-list>
  </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

[image: No image above the list]

Comment: Can you post a screenshot of where it is displaying?

Comment: Added the image.  I want the image to go above the list and below nav bar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are trying to access the image `post.acf.top_image_full_list` - which is within a 'post' object. However you do not create the 'post' object until further down in the list with the line `<a ng-repeat="post in posts"` - you are trying to use the 'post' object outside of the ng-repeat.